Issues with Build.gradle file
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/bless/Documents/myprojects/HikersAfrique/android/app/build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [extension 'flutter'] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           46.4s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I've tried writng the graddle file afresh, I've tried to create another project and shift the code in lib,depencies and all necssary configurations

Please, provide your app-level build.gradle file.

Do you have a VPN? Please turn it on and test it.
and update Kotlin version in build.gradle (1.8.0 or higher).
In the end, if it doesn't work clear the gradle cache and run again.
I hope it helps you :)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
